# monitor serial port that already open with java

Tags: java, serial-port

i am working on monitoring com port and get data as it is available, the port is being used by another program so is it possible to monitor the port without opening it
This is the code

```
package comtest;

import javax.comm.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PortTyper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            CommPortIdentifier com =
                    CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM2");

            CommPort thePort = com.open("port", 10);

            CopyThread output = new CopyThread(thePort.getInputStream(),
                    System.out);

            output.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class CopyThread extends Thread {

    InputStream theInput;
    OutputStream theOutput;


    CopyThread(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        theInput = in;
        theOutput = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = theInput.read(buffer);
                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                theOutput.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

so can i just see what the data come to the COM2 without

```
CommPort thePort = com.open("port", 10);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't monitor the serial port if it is opened by another program because a serial port can't be opened 2 times simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually try monitoring the serial port using softwares like PortMon.

However this software is only available till Windows NT.